# Call generic overload based on concrete type

Tags: c#, generics

When I run the below snippet

```cs
void Foo<T>(List<T> s) => s.ForEach(Foo);

void Foo(int t) => Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", t);

void Foo<T>(T t) => Console.WriteLine("T: {0}", t);

Foo(3);
Foo('a');
List<int> s = new List<int> { 1, 3 };
Foo(s);
```

I get the output:

```
int: 3
T: a
T: 1
T: 3
```

I want so that `Foo<T>(List<T> s)` calls the correct overload of Foo based on the type, `int` in this case, without having to write a `Foo(List<int> s)` implementation - which would be exactly the same as the generic one.

Expected output:

```
int: 3
T: a
int: 1
int: 3
```

I'm sure this a known thing. I don't know how to search for it. Thanks.

---

Actual problem is I want a generic method to take union of container types which might be recursive.

So, I have defined following overloads.

```cs
ISet<T> Union<T>(ISet<T> a, ISet<T> b);
IDictionary<T, U> Union<T, U>(IDictionary<T, U> a, IDictionary<T, U> b);

T Union<T>(T a, T b); // this is fallback for non-container types to stop the recursion
```

I expect the union for `IDictionary<string, ISet<string>>` to be computed recursively.

Comment: `s.ForEach(x => Foo((dynamic)x));` probably works. But I feel this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You might be approach a problem in a wrong way.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks, that works. your right, let me try to edit and add the minimal version of actual problem. my bad.

Comment: The correct overload for your code is `void Foo<T>(T t)` as the compiler considers `T` to be `object` (unless you add a `where  T : ` constraint). Since `int` is more specific than `object` the compiler uses the `void Foo<T>(T t)` method. Just because you call `void Foo(int t)` the correct overload, it doesn't make it so.

Comment: @Enigmativity but the compiler knows T is int at compile time when `void Foo<T>(IList<T>)` is called with `List<int>`. I was wondering if there were some type hints I could use to help the compiler.

Comment: You seem to think that the compiler will know better but consider that `void Foo<T>(List<T> s) => s.ForEach(Foo)` itself has to be compiled - and at the time *it* is compiled it has no knowledge beyond the generic type constraints applied to `T`. After that, the specific method to call has been compiled into the body of that method.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to solve these types of problems with a simple delegate repository.

```
private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _repository = new Dictionary<System.Type, Delegate>();

private void AddDelegate<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    _repository[typeof(T)] = action;
}

private Action<T> GetDelegate<T>()
{
    if (_repository.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        return (Action<T>)_repository[typeof(T)];
    }
    return (Action<T>)(Foo);
}
```

You can then change the `Foo<T>(List<T> s)` to this:

```
void Foo<T>(List<T> s) => s.ForEach(GetDelegate<T>());
```

Now you just need to register the overloads that you care about:

```
AddDelegate<int>(Foo);
```

Then when you run your code, as it was before, it now works as per your expectation:

```
Foo(3);
Foo('a');
List<int> s = new List<int> { 1, 3 };
Foo(s);
```

```
int: 3
T: a
int: 1
int: 3
```

Comment: very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

This unfortunately cannot itself be achieved by overrides.

Instead, you can achieve this with polymorphism, by creating a wrapper class with various implementations, but all implementing a common interface.

```
// Note how all the below are just stored as simple "IHandler"s
IHandler first = new IntHandler(3);
IHandler second = new Handler<char>('a');
IHandler third = new ListHandler(new IntHandler(3), new IntHandler(4), new Handler<char>('b'));

first.DoTheThing();
second.DoTheThing();
Console.WriteLine();
third.DoTheThing();

// Outputs:
// int: 3
// T: a
// 
// int: 3
// int: 4
// T: b

public interface IHandler
{
    void DoTheThing();
}

public class Handler<T> : IHandler
{
    protected readonly T _value;
    public Handler(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
    public virtual void DoTheThing() => Console.WriteLine($"T: {_value}");
}

public class IntHandler : Handler<int>
{
    public IntHandler(int value) : base(value)
    {
    }

    public override void DoTheThing() => Console.WriteLine($"int: {_value}");
}

public class ListHandler : Handler<IEnumerable<IHandler>>
{
    public ListHandler(params IHandler[] values) : base(values)
    {
    }

    public override void DoTheThing()
    {
        foreach (var handler in _value)
        {
            handler.DoTheThing();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. :( I was wondering if there was a type trickery I could use to hint the compiler. Using `dynamic` as suggested by sweeper in the comments works, but IDK if it good practice to use in production code. Take a +1!

Comment: There isn't, because within your code itself you can see the issue.  Inside of your `List<T>` function, if you hover over the value of `s` you will see it is a `T`, which means the compiler can't know "ahead of time" that you sometimes want the int version called. Polymorphism is the solution here, in fact you will want to look up Strategy Pattern ideally.

Answer (score 0):

Given the answers, I think the best way to do this with generics is to use `dynamic` and let the correct method overload be selected at runtime.

Credits to Sweeper:

```cs
Foo((dynamic)obj);
```